# Compare the key/values of two dictionaries and put into new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I know variations on this question already exist, but I cannot find one that matches exactly what I am trying to achieve. I have the following code, which included a solution I have taken from a solution to a similar question:

```
b = {"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0}
c = {"1":1,"4":4,"5":5}

d = [k for k in b if c.get(k, object()) > b[k]]

print d
```

What I want is to compare all the key and value pairs of the dictionary `b` with those of `c`. If a key and value pair is missing from `c` then the key/pair value of `b` is retained in the dictionary `d`, else the values in `c` are retained in `d`.

In the example above `d` should look like this:

```
d = {"1":1,"2":0,"3":0,"4":4,"5":5}
```

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax I need for the line `d =`, please?

Thanks

Comment: The code you posted compares the value `c[k]` with `b[k]`, but your description only refers to present vs. missing, not "only use the value in `c` if it's bigger".  What do you want to happen if `c["4"] == -6`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `if-else`condition in your comprehension, and also you dont need to use `get` when every thing is clear :

```
>>> d={k:c[k] if k in c and c[k]>b[k] else v for k,v in b.items()}
>>> d
{'1': 1, '3': 0, '2': 0, '5': 5, '4': 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your **actual** question

> What I want is to compare all the key and value pairs of the dictionary b with those of c. If a key and value pair is missing from c then the key/pair value of b is retained in the dictionary d, else the values in c are retained in d.

```
>>> b = {"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0}
>>> c = {"1":1,"4":4,"5":5}
>>> d = {k: c.get(k, b[k]) for k in b}
>>> d
{'1': 1, '3': 0, '2': 0, '5': 5, '4': 4}
```

In Python 3 you should use `collections.ChainMap`  (note this is slightly different in that it will take any key from `c`, not just the ones in `b`)

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> b = {"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0}
>>> c = {"1":1,"4":4,"5":5}
>>> d = ChainMap(c, b)
>>> d
ChainMap({'1': 1, '5': 5, '4': 4}, {'1': 0, '3': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 0})
>>> d['1'], d['2'], d['4']
(1, 0, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps this:

```
b = {"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0}
c = {"1":1,"4":4,"5":5}

d = {k:b[k] if not c.get(k)>b[k] else c[k] for k in b}

d
{'1': 1, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 4, '5': 5}
```

Or, if you want to unpack both key/values from `b` to compare:

```
{k:v if not c.get(k)>v else c[k] for k, v in b.iteritems()}
```

The part of **k:v** is treated as `key=k`, and `value=` `v` only if `k` doesn't exist in `c` and `c[k]` value is `>` `v`, otherwise take `v`.

And since `c.get(k)` returns **None** if `k` doesn't exist in c, and `None > v` will automatically translate to **False**.